# Javascript Css Tooltip who to Fix position when page ends

Tags: javascript, html, css, tooltip

Hello i had fallowing script and html codes for CSS tooltip. The problem is tooltip span part goes down when pages end. how can i change the position to top if page ends

Javascript :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        var tooltips = document.querySelectorAll('.tooltip span');
        window.onmousemove = function (e) {
            var x = (e.clientX + 20) + 'px',
                y = (e.clientY + 20) + 'px';
            for (var i = 0; i < tooltips.length; i++) {
                tooltips[i].style.top = y;
                tooltips[i].style.left = x;
            }
        };

    </script>
```

Css :

```
.tooltip {
    cursor: help; 
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    }
.tooltip span {
    display:none;
}
.tooltip:hover span {
    display:block;
    position:fixed;
    overflow:hidden;
}


    .classic { padding: 0.8em 1em; }
    * html a:hover { background: transparent; }
    .classic {
    z-index:1000;
    border:1px solid #111;
    background-color:#221f28;
    position: fixed;
    padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
    opacity:0.85;
    font:normal 10px Tahoma,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
    font: 11px arial,sans-serif;    
     -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=50)";

    }
    .tooltip h3,#tooltip div{margin:0;}
```

HTML part

```
<td  class='tooltip' style='height:100px;width:140px;margin:0 auto;' >
    <a class='tooltip' href=''>
    <img  src="http://i45.tinypic.com/2lbmg04.png"><span class='classic'>SomeText<br/>SomeText<br/>SomeText<br/>SomeText<br/>SomeText<br/>SomeText<br/>SomeText<br/>SomeText<br/>SomeText<br/>SomeText<br/>SomeText<br/>SomeText<br/>SomeText<br/>SomeText<br/>SomeText<br/>SomeText<br/>SomeText<br/>SomeText<br/>SomeText<br/>SomeText<br/>SomeText<br/>SomeText<br/>SomeText<br/>SomeText<br/>SomeText<br/>SomeText<br/>SomeText<br/></span>
    </a>
```

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/179uf3od/1/

Comment: Good job on posting the code! Would you mind turning it into a [code snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)?

Comment: JS fiddle added on first post

Answer (score 1):

You can run an if statement to check how close the mouse position is to the end of the page and then reverse where the tool tip is displayed. Below I am checking to see if the mouse cursor is within 100 pixels of the end of the page.

```
<script>

var tooltips = document.querySelectorAll('.tooltip span');
window.onmousemove = function (e) {
    var x, y;

    if( e.clientY > window.innerHeight - 100 ) {
        x = (e.clientX - 20);
        y = (e.clientY - 20);               
    } else {
        x = (e.clientX + 20);
        y = (e.clientY + 20);               
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < tooltips.length; i++) {
        tooltips[i].style.top = y + 'px';
        tooltips[i].style.left = x + 'px';
    }
};

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, you could probably use something like this:

```
 var tooltips = document.querySelectorAll('.tooltip span'),
     win_height = window.innerHeight;

window.onmousemove = function (e) {
  var x = (e.clientX + 20) + 'px',
      y = (e.clientY + 20) + 'px';

  for (var i = 0; i < tooltips.length; i++) {
    var maxY = win_height - tooltips[i].offsetHeight;
    if((e.clientY + 20) > maxY) y = maxY + 'px';

    tooltips[i].style.top = y;
    tooltips[i].style.left = x;
  }
};
```

What this is doing is setting a threshold for the Y value by taking the windows height and subtracting it from the tooltips height to prevent the tooltip from overflowing at the bottom of the page.

In order to get the tooltips height dynamically, you will have to change it from `display: none;` to `visibility : hidden`, else the height will always comeback as 0. And also set `visibility : visible;` on the `:hover` style.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/179uf3od/2/) demoing this solution.